# spring boot cold start taking too long on aws lambda and boot initializes twice

Tags: java, spring-boot, aws-lambda, aws-serverless, cold-start

this is strange but my spring boot api taking much longer that expected when deployed on aws lambda.
in the cloudwatch log, i see spring boot is starting up twice first with default profile and second with a profile i set.
Why should it boot twice.. that is significantly costing time..
**Source Code:**
*lambdahandler.java*

```
public class LambdaHandler implements RequestStreamHandler {

    private static SpringBootLambdaContainerHandler<AwsProxyRequest, AwsProxyResponse> handler;

    static {
        try {
            handler = SpringBootLambdaContainerHandler.getAwsProxyHandler(Application.class);
            handler.activateSpringProfiles("lambda");
        } catch (ContainerInitializationException e) {
            // Re-throw the exception to force another cold start
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new RuntimeException("Could not initialize Spring Boot application", e);
        }
    }
```

*application.java*

```
@SpringBootApplication
    public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
        }
```

both these files are in the same package

*config.java*

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@Profile("lambda")
public class Config {

    /**
     * Create required HandlerMapping, to avoid several default HandlerMapping instances being created
     */
    @Bean
    public HandlerMapping handlerMapping() {
        return new RequestMappingHandlerMapping();
    }

    /**
     * Create required HandlerAdapter, to avoid several default HandlerAdapter instances being created
     */
    @Bean
    public HandlerAdapter handlerAdapter() {
        return new RequestMappingHandlerAdapter();
    }
..
..

}
```

*pom.xml*

```
<dependency>
      <groupId>com.amazonaws.serverless</groupId>
      <artifactId>aws-serverless-java-container-spring</artifactId>
      <version>[0.1,)</version>
    </dependency>
<dependency>
      <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
      <artifactId>aws-lambda-java-core</artifactId>
      <version>1.2.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
      <artifactId>aws-lambda-java-events</artifactId>
      <version>3.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

**cloudwatch log**

```
    07:16:51.546 [main] INFO com.amazonaws.serverless.proxy.internal.LambdaContainerHandler - Starting Lambda Container Handler
:: Spring Boot ::                        
    2020-09-05 07:16:52.724  INFO 1 --- [           main] lambdainternal.LambdaRTEntry             : Starting LambdaRTEntry on 169.254.184.173 with PID 1 (/var/runtime/lib/LambdaJavaRTEntry-1.0.jar started by sbx_user1051 in /)
    2020-09-05 07:16:52.726  INFO 1 --- [           main] lambdainternal.LambdaRTEntry             : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
    2020-09-05 07:16:52.906  INFO 1 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@1e81f4dc: startup date [Sat Sep 05 07:16:52 UTC 2020]; root of context hierarchy
    
    ..
    ..
    2020-09-05 07:16:57.222  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet': initialization completed in 40 ms
    :: Spring Boot ::                        
    2020-09-05 07:16:57.442  INFO 1 --- [           main] lambdainternal.LambdaRTEntry             : Starting LambdaRTEntry on 169.254.184.173 with PID 1 (/var/runtime/lib/LambdaJavaRTEntry-1.0.jar started by sbx_user1051 in /)
    2020-09-05 07:16:57.442  INFO 1 --- [           main] lambdainternal.LambdaRTEntry             : The following profiles are active: lambda
    2020-09-05 07:16:57.445  INFO 1 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@5ef60048: startup date [Sat Sep 05 07:16:57 UTC 2020]; root of context hierarchy
```

Answer (score 2):

## Why should it boot twice ?

I suspect your code change with activateSpringProfiles force reinitialisation.

```java
handler.activateSpringProfiles("lambda");
```

https://github.com/awslabs/aws-serverless-java-container/blob/master/aws-serverless-java-container-spring/src/main/java/com/amazonaws/serverless/proxy/spring/SpringBootLambdaContainerHandler.java#L149

Try setting active profile with env variable `SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE` as part of lambda configuration file.

## Java and serverless

If you use java for serverless application like AWS lambdas  I would recommend for looking a framework which supports Ahead-of-Time compilation which will boost a lot your application start.

For instance have a look at  Micronaut, Quarkus  using with Graalvm.
Spring Boot is not the best option using with directly with AWS lambdas.